# How to select a sheet from a user input box?

Tags: excel, vba

I to ask the user if they want data or a graph.

If the user selects Yes, verify selected input is a valid sheet name.

- If not valid, the input box will display again until valid sheet name.
- If the sheet is valid, then I need the sheet to be selected or show up whenever the user enters a valid value. I hope that makes sense.

For example, if the user enters (10-1) that is a valid sheet or (1-1) valid sheet but if it is (14-1) or (a-a) that is not a valid sheet.

Note I have not gotten to the graphing part, so do not worry about if the user selects No.

```vb
Sub InputValidation()
    Dim str As String
    Dim inp As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    str = MsgBox("Do you want to select a dataset (Yes) or a Graph (No)", vbQuestion + vbYesNo)
    
    If str = vbYes Then
        inp = InputBox("Please enter a load value (10 or a load and trial (10-1)")
        If StrPtr(inp) = 0 Then
            If MsgBox("Do you really want to QUIT", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then MsgBox "Thank You Goodbye"
                Exit Sub
            End If
        ElseIf inp = "#-#" Or "##-#" Then
            If Sheets(ws).Name = inp Then
                Worksheets(inp).Activate
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "This load and test cannot be found"

    
    If str = vbNo Then
        inp = InputBox("Please enter a load value (10 or a load and trial (10-1)")
        If StrPtr(inp) = 0 Then
            If MsgBox("Do you really want to QUIT", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then MsgBox "Thank You Goodbye"
            Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    End If
        
End Sub
```

Comment: The "checking the sheet name is valid" portion of the code needs to be in some type of loop for it to keep trying until a valid name is given. Most commonly I believe 'Do While' is used. (Or perhaps the following can be repurposed to suit your use?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24709671/3654325

Comment: yeah I got that I am going to add that at the end so I don't get in an infinite loop. My problem right now is when the user inputs 10-1 then the sheet does not activate.

Comment: Line 14 "End If" should be somewhere else? Probably after "MsgBox "This load and test cannot be found". Do you know how to step through code using Debug F8?

Comment: Also 'ElseIf inp = "#-#" Or inp = "##-#" Then', or a Type Mismatch happens when excel tries to evaluate False Or "##-#"

Comment: I would do this differently. I will show a userform with 2 radio button and 1 combobox. The radio buttons are for `Data` and `Graph`. Based on which radio button is selected, I will show all sheet names or graph names in the combobox so that the user can choose.  No need to ask the user to type and then validate it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you close all you `if` statements when using indentation?
The way you have now set it implies that the last `End if` is covering the entire `str = vbYes` scope, i.e. if `str = vbNo` nothing happens?

```
Sub InputValidation()
    Dim str As String
    Dim inp As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    str = MsgBox("Do you want to select a dataset (Yes) or a Graph (No)", vbQuestion + vbYesNo)

    If str = vbYes Then
        inp = InputBox("Please enter a load value (10 or a load and trial (10-1)")
        If StrPtr(inp) = 0 Then
            If MsgBox("Do you really want to QUIT", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then MsgBox "Thank You Goodbye"
                Exit Sub
            'End If
        ElseIf inp = "#-#" Or "##-#" Then
            If Sheets(ws).Name = inp Then
                Worksheets(inp).Activate
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "This load and test cannot be found"
        End If '=> added this End If as it will otherwise skip to end of sequence
    ElseIf str = vbNo Then
        inp = InputBox("Please enter a load value (10 or a load and trial (10-1)")
        If StrPtr(inp) = 0 Then
            If MsgBox("Do you really want to QUIT", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then MsgBox "Thank You Goodbye"
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If

End Sub
```

I also think your below line is incorrect?

```
ElseIf inp = "#-#" Or "##-#" Then
```

It will give a `Type Mismatch` error? (Error 13)
You could contemplate using a regex for this assessment or simply use something like the below?

```
ElseIf inp like "*-*" Then
```

Which would also do the trick?

The subsequent statement tries to select the Worksheet but that won't work as you have not set the `ws` object anywhere? So the below line is incorrect in many ways:

```
If Sheets(ws).Name = inp Then
```

Please see below code that will give you a good base to start from?
This would also get rid of the unnecessary `inp = "#-#"` comparison

```
Private Function SheetExists(name As String) As Boolean
    
    SheetExists = False
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.name = name Then SheetExists = True: Exit Function
    Next
    
End Function

Private Function ConfirmEndSub()
    
    ConfirmEndSub = MsgBox("Do you really want to QUIT", vbYesNo + vbQuestion)
    If ConfirmEndSub = vbYes Then
        MsgBox "Thank You Goodbye"
    End If
    
End Function

Sub InputValidation()
    Dim str As String
    Dim inp As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    str = MsgBox("Do you want to select a dataset (Yes) or a Graph (No)", vbQuestion + vbYesNo)

    If str = vbYes Then
        inp = InputBox("Please enter a load value (10 or a load and trial (10-1)")
        If StrPtr(inp) = 0 Then
            Reply = ConfirmEndSub
            If Reply = vbYes Then Exit Sub
        ElseIf SheetExists(inp) Then
            Worksheets(inp).Activate
        Else
            MsgBox "This load and test cannot be found"
        End If
    ElseIf str = vbNo Then
        inp = InputBox("Please enter a load value (10 or a load and trial (10-1)")
        If StrPtr(inp) = 0 Then
            Reply = ConfirmEndSub
            If Reply = vbYes Then Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This leaves entirely out of consideration that depsite the initial `vbYesNo` answer the user will always get the input box? Not sure if that is the intention, but alas that is how it was written.

One other consideration is that if the user selects not to Quit, the call is not returning to the request for input? => I.e. it is still ending the routine...

Comment: That makes more sense thank you @mtholen I am new to Vba and trying to learn and do my best. Is there any good links that you have found that might be useful in my next problem?

Comment: That would depend on what your next problem is... But generally SO is a pretty good source of information. Just continue learning, it will pay off.

Comment: By the way, if my answer has answered your question, then tick this answer as the answer. That will help SO stay correct